# Match Observation from One Table to Another Table Variable Consisting of Strings

Tags: r, stringr

I have two datasets called A and B.

```
 library(data.table)
 Farm.Type <- c("Fruits","Vegetables","Livestock")
 Produce.All <- c("Apple, Orange, Pears, Strawberries","Broccoli, Cabbage, Spinach","Cow, Pig, Chicken")

 Store <- c("Convenience","Wholesale","Grocery","Market")
 Produce <- c("Oranges","Watermelon","Cabbage","Pig")
 Farm <- c("Fruits","","Vegetables","Livestock")

 A <- data.table(Farm.Type, Produce.All)
 B <- data.table(Store, Produce)
```

I am trying to identify what Farm.Type the Produce in table B falls into in table A, without changing the format of the two tables in order to pull the Farm.Type field into table B. Such that the data frame looks like

```
 C <- data.table(Store, Produce, Farm)
```

I have tried using %in% in the following way:

```
 B$Farm[B$Produce %in% A$Produce.All] <- A$Farm.Type
```

but because the A$Produce.All field is a string with commas, It does not match.

Is there a way to search through the string (A$Produce.All) to find the match for B$Produce?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you reticent to change the format of table A?

Comment: Hi, I am not really opposed to changing Table A. However, I am curious if there's a possible solution without going through the additional steps of transforming table A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Farm.Type <- c("Fruits","Vegetables","Livestock")
Produce.All <- c("Apple, Oranges, Pears, Strawberries","Broccoli, Cabbage, Spinach","Cow, Pig, Chicken")

Store <- c("Convenience","Wholesale","Grocery","Market")
Produce <- c("Orange","Watermelon","Cabbage","Pig")
Farm <- c("Fruits","","Vegetables","Livestock")
```

There's no need for `data.table` here, so I'm foregoing the use of that. You'd be far better off transforming the data since you have to do gyrations like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringi)

A <- data_frame(Farm.Type, Produce.All)
B <- data_frame(Store, Produce)

map(B$Produce, ~stri_detect_regex(A$Produce.All, sprintf("[[:space:],]*%s[[:space:],]*", .))) %>% 
  map(which) %>% 
  map_chr(~A$Farm.Type[ifelse(length(.)==0, NA, .)][1])
```

otherwise. (You still have to add that to the B data frame)

versus:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mutate(A, Produce.All=stri_split_regex(Produce.All, ", ")) %>% 
  unnest(Produce.All) -> A_long

left_join(B, A_long, by=c("Produce"="Produce.All"))
```

And, I sure hope this wasn't homework.

Comment: (It's not base R if you use `data.table` :-) You shld make this an answer @Jota.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah I see it can get convoluted when working with the strings. I had thought of using some sort of for or while loop and doing combined with a grep function, but I see how it is simpler to just transform the data.

Answer (score 2):

Riffing off of hrbrmstr's answer, but sticking with `data.table` and some base R:

```
longA <- 
  stack(
    setNames(
      strsplit(A[, Produce.All], ", "),
      A[, Farm.Type]
    )
  )

merge(longA, B, by.x = "values", by.y = "Produce", all.y = TRUE)
#      values        ind       Store
#1    Cabbage Vegetables     Grocery
#2    Oranges       <NA> Convenience
#3        Pig  Livestock      Market
#4 Watermelon       <NA>   Wholesale

# Or using a data.table merge, if you like
setDT(longA)[B, on = c(values = "Produce")]
```

Of course, "Orange" doesn't match to "Oranges," and the inconsistent appearance of plural and singular versions of the items in each data set makes the merging a bit more challenging.  If that is also something that needs to be done, I would suggest mapping plural versions to singular before doing the merge.